# "Wget --retry" command - shell script in jenkins

Tags: wget, jenkins, groovy

Is is possible to get the value of how many times the wget command retries? and how?
I want to include the number of retries in the email, to be send after the build in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

According to Man Pages

‘--tries=number’

Set number of tries to number. Specify 0 or ‘inf’ for infinite retrying. The default is to retry 20 times, with the exception of fatal errors like “connection refused” or “not found” (404), which are not retried.

Comment: thanks, but I have set the number of tries to 0 means infinite, now I want to know in what number of retry the wget command build successfully or stopped.